# What is this style of navigation sidebar called and is there an open source Javascript library for it?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to build a sidebar navigation for an online book much like apple did here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/

(note it has collapsable entries)

and to my surprise I'm having a hard time finding a good off the shelve javascript startingpoint to build from.

What is this style of navigation sidebar called?

Are there any open source Javascript libraries that provide this style of navigation?

Answer (score 1):

I would use jQuery expand collapse, a good example can be found here http://www.adipalaz.com/experiments/jquery/expand.html

You can style the divs however you want and make it appear as if it's a menu, index, etc